# How to use wildcard in an Access VBA if then statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 22 items for a text box in the dropdown selection menu. 7 of them start with "Makeup - Answer1-7", 7 of them start with "Ad-Hoc Answer1-7" and the other 8 will be the else statement. The below code is what I have been using since it was the only answer to cause the Makeup_Date.visible = True. How can I do the same with multiple items 7 - Makeup & 7 - Ad-Hoc. I tried using a wildcard but it didn't work.

Example text box drop down items list
Makeup - Answer 1
Makeup - Answer 2...
Makeup - Answer 7
Ad-Hoc - Answer 1
Ad-Hoc- Answer 2...
Ad-Hoc- Answer 7
Other 8 Items...

```
Private Sub Week1_Attended_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Refresh
If (Me.Week1_Attended = "YES - MAKEUP COMPLETED") Then
    Me.Week1_Makeup_Date.Visible = True
Else
    Me.Week1_Makeup_Date.Visible = False
End If
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator

Comment: If item start with "Makeup", You may simply check **If (Left(Me.Week1_Attended,6)="Makeup") then** or use function **InStr**

Comment: I didn't wait. It's works great thanks!

Comment: Also, `Me.Week1_Attended = "YES - MAKEUP COMPLETED"` will evaluate to TRUE/FALSE, `Me.Week1_Makeup_Date.Visible = True` takes TRUE/FALSE.... so `Me.Week1_Makeup_Date.Visible = (Me.Week1_Attended = "YES - MAKEUP COMPLETED")` can replace your whole `IF...END IF` statement.